# Can't seem to grab alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the "alt" attribute of an image inside "uCW", but nothing's printing.

Here's the image:

```
<img class="i09qtzwb n7fi1qx3 datstx6m pmk7jnqg j9ispegn kr520xx4 k4urcfbm bixrwtb6" height="261" src="https://external-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAayZaQwp_d10l4&w=750&h=391&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.buzzfeed.com%2Fbuzzfeed-static%2Fstatic%2F2020-04%2F28%2F13%2Fasset%2F36517ba3257e%2Fsub-buzz-279-1588079535-1.png%3Fcrop%3D768%3A402%3B0%2C8&cfs=1&ext=jpg&_nc_hash=AQBIX7qpH_aPKJby" width="500" alt="A Reporter Went On "GMA" Wearing No Pants. He Didn't Realize We Could All See.">
```

(Sorry about the long line, I couldn't figure out how to get it to wrap.)

Here's my code:

```
var title = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("alt");
console.log(title);
```

Nearly identical code works fine for grabbing the URL:

```
var image = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src");
console.log(image);
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that the `alt` tag is corrupted (because of the double-quote marks halfway through it, which cuts it off), your code seems fine to me. Demo https://jsfiddle.net/tcnezd9k/ - it fetches the value correctly.

Comment: As ADyson says, you're not allowed to use double-quotes within the double-quotes of the alt attribute: `alt="A Reporter Went On "GMA" Wearing No Pants..."` should be `alt="A Reporter Went On &quot;GMA&quot; Wearing No Pants..."`

Comment: Hm, it does seem to work in jfiddle, but doesn't in my console/browser ... any reason that could be? the other bit of code (for the URL) works fine.)

Comment: Where the quotes changed as mentioned by others? ... If so, maybe clear the browser cache and retry. If it _still_ doesn't seem to work, update the code in the question with your latest.

Comment: It continues not to work — even on divs that don't have the double quote. I'm trying to get the same text a different way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493094/how-to-just-grab-the-first-block-of-text-in-a-div