# How to just grab the first block of text in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to just grab a link's text — the stuff between `<a href>` and `</a>`.

```
var title = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]').text();
console.log(title);
```

Right now, my code is grabbing text from multiple links (there are multiple https://l.facebook links in the div) and combining them. Is there any way to just grab the text from the first link? I've tried

```
var title = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]').text()[0];
console.log(title);
```

But I just get an error: "Error occurred when adding button. TypeError: $(...).find(...)[0].text is not a function."

Comment: Depends on what you mean. The first `<p>` element? The first line of a text element? The first amount until a newline character (enter)?

Comment: All the stuff in between <a href ...> and </a>. The text within the link. Right now, it's grabbing all the text in multiple links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var title = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]:first').text();
```

This will limit your search to the first matching element.

Just learned that `:first` is deprecated in the current jQuery version. 
https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ .

So, replace it with `.first()`:

```
var title = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]').first().text();
```